# Calling parent method that is overridden by son, with another method of son

Tags: java, extension-methods, overriding

I want to call a parent method from the son, and I don't know how the parent method works:

The parent `A` have the method: `myMethod(double d)`.

```
public class B extends A{

    //overrides
    public void myMethod(double d){
         doSomthing();
         super.myMethod(d);
    }

    public void anotherMethod(...){
         super.myMethod(d);
    }

}
```

`instanceOfB.myMethod(d)` works fine.

The problem is `instanceOfB.anotherMethod(...)` it just do the `instanceOfB.myMethod(d)`.

I want instance of `B` to run `myMethod` of the parent.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide us with the implementation of the class A.

Comment: You mean that `b.anotherMethod(...)` runs `myMethod` of `A`?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong. It does call super.myMethod(). I assembled this code quickly to test

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        B b= new B();
        b.anotherMethod(); //the output is 1 which is correct
        b.myMethod(2); //the output is somth and then 2 which is correct
    }

    public static class A {
        public void myMethod(double d) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A{

        //overrides
        public void myMethod(double d){
             doSomthing();
             super.myMethod(d);
        }

        private void doSomthing() {
            System.out.println("somth");
        }

        public void anotherMethod(){
             super.myMethod(1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I also think that. But what does your statement has to do with my example? You are showing us that you think good? Those are inner classes

Comment: That does not mean that super.myMethod() in anotherMethod() does not run it. It does

Comment: and yet, it doesnt work, i tried the simplest thing there, exactly the same way u written it..